# Changing df and col in a Function

Tags: r, function

I am having trouble creating a function that will allow me to, on the fly, change the data frame (df) and column (col). 
Each column has two possible entries, e.g., left or right.

Conceptually at least, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
 myfun = function(df, col){
 mean( df$RT[ df$col == levels(df$col)[1] ] ) - mean( df$RT[ df$col == levels(df$col)[2] ] )
```

so I could enter something like:

```
myfun( df = m, col = turn_direction )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't use `$` programmatically. `df$col` will always be `df$col`, exactly as written. You can however do `df[,col]` where `col <- "name"` as a string.

Comment: @thelatemail Thank you...but even   df = "a"; mean( df[,"RT"] ) fails to work...

Comment: It won't, but you can make that sort of thing work e.g.:- `f <- function(df, col) {df[,col]}; f(iris,"Species")` for example